# Convert Bytes into a class of dictionary, filter data according to two values and store the output in a list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, bytesio

I am a beginner in this and any help would be much appreciated! I have Bytes which I converted into a class of dictionary.

my dataset looks like that:

```
{'color': 'blue', 'size': 'big', 'name': 'clara', 'word': 'hey'}
{'color': 'red', 'size': 'small', 'name': 'John', 'word': 'no'}
{'color': 'orange', 'size': 'big', 'name': 'Paul', 'word': 'bye'}
{'color': 'orange', 'size': 'big', 'name': 'clara', 'word': 'bye'}
```

I am trying to filter my data to get only color = orange and word = bye as below and to create a list of dictionary in order to obtain a result as per below:

```
[{'color': 'orange', 'size': 'big', 'name': 'Paul', 'word': 'bye'}
{'color': 'orange', 'size': 'big', 'name': 'clara', 'word': 'bye'}]
```

my current code is like that:

```
f = res.decode("utf-8")
reader_list = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(f))

ls=[]
for row in reader_list:
   
    dico = dict(row)
    
    for (k,v) in dico.items():
        if dico['color'] == "orange" and dico['word'] == 'bye':
            
            for row in dico:
                if row not in ls:
                    ls.append(row)
                    print(ls)
```

but the output I get is as per below:

```
['color',] 
['color', 'size',] 
['color', 'size', 'name',] 
['color', 'size', 'name', 'word',]
```

which seems to correspond to my column names instead of:

```
[{'color': 'orange', 'size': 'big', 'name': 'Paul', 'word': 'bye'}, {'color': 'orange', 'size': 'big', 'name': 'clara', 'word': 'bye'}]
```

Comment: `ls.append` does not return a value, so that explains the `None` you are getting from doing `print(l)` as `l` is where your code assigned that `None` result.  If you do `print(ls)` instead you will find the values.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply! printing ls does not return my expected output. I get the output below:
`
['color',]
['color', 'size',]
['color', 'size', 'name',]
['color', 'size', 'name', 'word',]
`
which seems to correspond to my column names instead of:
`
[{'color': 'orange', 'size': 'big', 'name': 'Paul', 'word': 'bye'}
{'color': 'orange', 'size': 'big', 'name': 'clara', 'word': 'bye'}] 
`

Comment: Rather than trying to do 3 levels of for loops and the accompanied if statements, please print out what `dico` actually is per row, and there is no real need to iterate down individual `dico.items()` as they should be fully formed entries, your additional loops is needlessly going through individual columns which does not sound like what you want to do. Do your checks with that `if` statement and if that's true, then do `ls.append(row)`.

Comment: thanks! my code looks much better I changed it to:
`import csv
import io
f = res.decode("utf-8")
reader_list = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(f))


ls=[]
for row in reader_list:
    dico = dict(row)
    if dico['color'] == "orange" and dico['word'] == 'bye':
            ls.append(row)`

It doesnt completely give me the expected output my data type is ordereddict while I would like a list of dictionary. if i do "print(dico)" instead of " ls.append(row)"  I get the expected output but as a class of dictionary. Do you know how i can get my expected out as a list of dico?thks

Comment: If you printed `dico` which was your desired contents, but you instead appended `row`, but want to see `dico` inside the list instead, wouldn't you want to append `dico` instead to get what you want?  Your question wasn't very clear and the code was all over the place so I provided `ls.append(row)` as that was literally what you had in the code, it's up to you to figure out what exactly you want to achieve for yourself.

Comment: its working as excepted thanks!